# Using rollmean filtering out NA with threshold

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, rollapply

I am trying to apply a rollapply mean function to a dataframe with large chunks of missing data and single points interspersed throughout the missing data. Using my current form of rollapply, only one non-NaN value is needed and averaged to all surrounding values. My goal is to keep the values that have at least half of the values averaged within them, and remove all values that are the result of over 50% `NaN` data. Below is a simple example I made

```
library(zoo)

a <- c(0:20)
ind <- c(10:15)
ind2 <- c(10:12,14)
b <- a
b[ind] <- NaN
c <- a
c[ind2] <- NaN
df <- data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
dfroll <- as.data.frame(rollapply(df,width=5,mean,na.rm=T,fill=NA))
```

This results in the following data.frame

```
dfroll
    a    b        c
1  NA   NA       NA
2  NA   NA       NA
3   2  2.0  2.00000
4   3  3.0  3.00000
5   4  4.0  4.00000
6   5  5.0  5.00000
7   6  6.0  6.00000
8   7  6.5  6.50000
9   8  7.0  7.00000
10  9  7.5  7.50000
11 10  8.0 10.00000
12 11  NaN 12.00000
13 12  NaN 13.00000
14 13 15.0 13.66667
15 14 15.5 14.25000
16 15 16.0 15.50000
17 16 16.5 16.00000
18 17 17.0 17.00000
19 18 18.0 18.00000
20 NA   NA       NA
21 NA   NA       NA
```

For this example, I would like all values that have >= 3 `NaN` values to result in `NaN`. This would be rows 10:15 on column b, and rows 10:13 on column c. How would I go about setting up this threshold to pass `NaN` rather than the averaged value if there is limited data around the cell?

Desired result:

```
bdesired <- dfroll$b
bdesired[c(10:15)] <- NaN
cdesired <- dfroll$c
cdesired[c(10:13)] <- NaN
dfdesired <- data.frame(a=dfroll$a,b=bdesired,c=cdesired)
```

```
 dfdesired
    a    b        c
1  NA   NA       NA
2  NA   NA       NA
3   2  2.0  2.00000
4   3  3.0  3.00000
5   4  4.0  4.00000
6   5  5.0  5.00000
7   6  6.0  6.00000
8   7  6.5  6.50000
9   8  7.0  7.00000
10  9  NaN      NaN
11 10  NaN      NaN
12 11  NaN      NaN
13 12  NaN      NaN
14 13  NaN 13.50000
15 14  NaN 14.33333
16 15 16.0 16.00000
17 16 16.5 16.50000
18 17 17.0 17.00000
19 18 18.0 18.00000
20 NA   NA       NA
21 NA   NA       NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Define a function which returns NaN if there are `thresh` or more NA's in its input and returns mean of the non-NA's otherwise.  Then use it with `rollapply`.   Convert that to a data frame if desired using `as.data.frame` but since the data is entirely numeric leaving it as a matrix may be sufficient.

```
w <- 5
thresh <- w/2

Mean <- function(x, thresh) if (sum(is.na(x)) > thresh) NaN else mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
rollapply(df, w, Mean, thresh = thresh, fill = NA)
```

**2)** Another possibility is to check if there are more than thresh NA's in each cell and if so return NaN and otherwise return the rolling mean. Again use `as.data.frame` on the result if a data frame is needed.  (1) has the advantage over this one that it only calls `roll*` once instead of twice.

```
w <- 5
thresh <- w/2

ifelse(rollsum(is.na(df), w, fill = NA) > thresh, NaN, 
    rollmean(df, w, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `across(everything()` you can do the operation over all columns, then with `rollsum(is.na())` we count the number of `NAs`, and only if that is not 3 or higher we calculate the `rollmean`.

I only noticed some of your values for the `c-variable` are slightly different in your `dfroll` compared to in your `dfdesired`. My results match those in `dfroll`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~ifelse(rollsum(is.na(.x), 5, fill = NA) > 2, NaN, rollmean(.x, 5, fill = NA, na.rm = T))))


    a    b        c
1  NA   NA       NA
2  NA   NA       NA
3   2  2.0  2.00000
4   3  3.0  3.00000
5   4  4.0  4.00000
6   5  5.0  5.00000
7   6  6.0  6.00000
8   7  6.5  6.50000
9   8  7.0  7.00000
10  9  NaN      NaN
11 10  NaN      NaN
12 11  NaN      NaN
13 12  NaN      NaN
14 13  NaN 13.66667
15 14  NaN 14.25000
16 15 16.0 15.50000
17 16 16.5 16.00000
18 17 17.0 17.00000
19 18 18.0 18.00000
20 NA   NA       NA
21 NA   NA       NA
```